# Is there a way to reward Items based off scoreboard points?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a server based on PVP and I have set up a scoreboard that displays a players kills. I was wondering if, say for example, a player reached 50 kills could I give them a reward? (e.g diamond axe)

I have tried a bit, but I am stumped. I tried `give @a [scores={kills=50}] minecraft:diamond_axe` but it doesn't work. I did make sure to set my points to over 50.

The scoreboard is called "kills" I am on 1.15 Java Edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command only checks if your points are exactly 50. To test for values more then 50 you need to write: `[scores={kills=50..}]`